# Multiple arguments vs a tuple argument

Tags: functional-programming, language-agnostic, language-design

In functional languages without type checking, is there any substantial disadvantage (apart from readability) to limiting all functions to take exactly one argument - that is, replacing multi-argument functions with functions that take a tuple as an argument?

(I saw [some comments](http://jayconrod.com/posts/14/currying-and-why-we-dont-pass-arguments-as-tuples) about it being somewhat more difficult to design the type system when functions accept tuples. I am interested in considerations unrelated to this issue.)

Comment: Multiple arguments, used in moderation, can make it more apparent which are required and which are optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a fundamental disadvantage to using a tuple, versus having multiple parameters: you lose the ability to use partial applications and currying.

Partial function application and currying are central features to functional languages. The fact that all functions are represented as a series of one-parameter functions that call each other, allows parameters to be "applied", eg in the following example, `double` is defined as a partially applied `multiply` function:

```
let multiply x y = x * y    
let double = multiply 2
let num1 = 10
let num2 = double num1
```

Replace `x y` with a tuple, `(x, y)` and suddenly the power of partial applications is removed. This is a very real issue in F#, which curries all functions. As a result, to enable interoperability with other .NET languages, the parameters for methods of all non-F# assemblies are treated as tuples. This means that partial application of those methods is not possible.

Comment: On the other hand, sometimes you want to use a product type precisely to *prevent* currying, in situations where the partially applied function would be meaningless. For a (somewhat contrived) example, consider a function `complexNorm` which computed the norm of a complex number, which are represented by a real and imaginary component. It wouldn't make sense to pass just the real value first to the function and obtain a partially applied function expecting an imaginary component.

Comment: Of course, many functional languages that don't auto-curry all function definitions do have convenient syntax to perform partial application, e.g. `f (x, _)` or `f (x, *)`. It can still be done manually with a lambda `\y -> f (x, y)`. Given a sufficiently powerful type system (e.g. one that defines tuples recursively), it's also possible to create a function to curry functions.

Comment: @amon so only `auto-currying` becomes impossible, while `currying` and `partial applications` can still be done with a little fancier syntax?

Comment: @max yes of course. For example if we have `def f(a, b, c)` in Python, we can turn it into a curried function like `lambda a: lambda b: lambda c: f(a, b, c)`. We could partially-apply just `b=42` like `lambda a, c: f(a, 42, c)`. Any language can do this as long as it has some form of closures. Single-argument functions are occasionally an annoyance, but they do not fundamentally constrain the language. Auto-currying as in Haskell is needed though to program in point-free style (avoiding explicit arguments), which is sometimes more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

The author of that blog post seems to be ignoring that most languages with generic types and subtypings have some way of expressing variance in their generic parameters. They write:

> So here's the issue: if we have a function that accepts arguments of type Tuple, and we want to pass it a tuple of arguments of type Tuple, we can only do this when A = X, and B = Y. If X is a subtype of A or Y is a subtype of B, we will get a type error. Subsumption is broken. Suddenly, you can't pass a String as an argument to a function that accepts Objects.

But actually, a tuple can be defined as something like:

```
case class Tuple2[+T1, +T2]
```

in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Tuple2.html) and other similar languages (C# or Java) even if it isn't always defined so, which gives it the proper variance.

Even though this is not a problem there are some tradeoffs between the two:

Pro multiple arguments:

- Makes optional, named and variadic arguments quite straightforward.
- Slight possible performance benefit (no tuples have to be created).
- Can have as many arguments as you want, without the language having to provide up to `Tuple20` say.

Pro tuples:

- Tuples are themselves values that can be passed around and transformed.
- Requires the language to support a nice tuple syntax to be usable.

As David Arno has pointed out, both tuples as single arguments and multiple arguments have the same disadvantage against fully curried arguments: they cannot be partially applied.

**Edit**:

So I might have misread the question, though I think it's vague on this point. For clarity, there are three ways a function might "take multiple arguments". The first is by *actually taking multiple arguments*, which is what the majority of programming languages do. For example, in Scala,

```
def concatenateMulti(left: String, right: String): String = left + right
```

the second is to take a single argument that is a tuple or record, e.g.

```
def concatenateTuple(args: Tuple2[String, String]): String = args._1 + args._2
```

and the third is to take a function that returns a partially applied function

```
def concatenateSingle(left: String): (String => String) = (right: String) => left + right
```

I assumed the author was asking after the first versus the second whereas it seems they were more interested in the second versus the third

Comment: Could you clarify the distinction between `tuples as single arguments` and as `multiple arguments`? If I understand correctly, my original question is about tuples representing multiple arguments, and I understand why the simple currying wouldn't work in that case. But what is the other case you're referring to?

Comment: @max, does my edit address it?

Comment: Yes, and I did mean (1) vs (2) in my question.